# Python dictionary conversion

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a Python dictionary:

```
adict = {
    'col1': [
        {'id': 1, 'tag': '#one#two'},
        {'id': 2, 'tag': '#two#'},
        {'id': 1, 'tag': '#one#three#'}
    ]
}
```

I want the result as follows:

```
Id tag
1  one,two,three
2  two
```

Could someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: use `for`-loop to work with dictionary and convert it to list of lists or new dictionary.

Comment: Special order of tags in the result is required?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
d={'col1':[{'id':1,'tag':'#one#two'},{'id':2,'tag':'#two#'},{'id':1,'tag':'#one#three#'}]}

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in d:
    for k in d[i]:
        t = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(k, orient='index').T
        t["tag"] = t["tag"].str.replace("#",",")
        df = pd.concat([df,t])

tf = df.groupby(["id"])["tag"].apply(lambda x : ",".join(set(''.join(list(x)).strip(",").split(","))))
```

Comment: It looks like an inefficient solution, iteration through nested dicts will give `O(n^2)`

Comment: I did not use for loop but used your groupby query and got the  result                                               df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df[["col1","col2"]] = pd.DataFrame(df.col1.values.tolist(),index=df.index)
df['col1'] = df.col1.str.replace('#',',')
df = df.groupby(["col2"])["col1"].apply(lambda x : ",".join(set(''.join(list(x)).strip(",").split(","))))

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1':[{'id':1,'tag':'#one#two'},{'id':2,'tag':'#two#'},{'id':1,'tag':'#one#three#'}]}


df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['Id'] = df.col1.apply(lambda x: x['id'])

df['tag'] = df.col1.apply(lambda x: ''.join(list(','.join(x['tag'].split('#')))[1:]))

df.drop(columns = 'col1', inplace = True)
```

```
Output:
Id Tag
1  one, two
2  two
1  one, three
```

Comment: This is not the same output that OP expects.

Answer (score 0):

If order of tags is important first remove trailing `#` and split by `#`, then per groups remove duplicates and `join`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d['col1'])
df['tag'] = df['tag'].str.strip('#').str.split('#')
f = lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys([z for y in x for z in y]).keys())
df = df.groupby('id')['tag'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
   id            tag
0   1  one,two,three
1   2            two
```

If order of tags is not important for remove duplicates use `set`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d['col1'])
df['tag'] = df['tag'].str.strip('#').str.split('#')
f = lambda x: ','.join(set([z for y in x for z in y]))
df = df.groupby('id')['tag'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
   id            tag
0   1  three,one,two
1   2            two
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dic=[{'col1':[{'id':1,'tag':'#one#two'},{'id':2,'tag':'#two#'},{'id':1,'tag':'#one#three#'}]}]

row=[]
for key in dic:
    data=key['col1']
    for rows in data:
        row.append(rows)
df=pd.DataFrame(row)
print(df)
```

o

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 0):

I tried as below

```
import pandas as pd
a = {'col1':[{'id':1, 'tag':'#one#two'},{'id':2, 'tag':'#two#'},{'id':1, 'tag':'#one#three#'}]}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df[["col1", "col2"]] = pd.DataFrame(df.col1.values.tolist(), index = df.index)
df['col1'] = df.col1.str.replace('#', ',')
df = df.groupby(["col2"])["col1"].apply(lambda x : ",".join(set(''.join(list(x)).strip(",").split(","))))

O/P:
col2
1    one,two,three
2    two
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please "edit" to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer